# Custom edit and delete components on row DataGrid MUI v5 component hovered

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI or [MUI v5](https://mui.com/) components for the UI library in my React Js app.

I'm creating a custom edit and delete row inside the `DataGrid`/`DataGridPro` component.

The specification is to show edit and delete icons for the hovered row but not by adding a new column (not adding an action column). I found the example for a private dashboard here.
[image]

So if the user decreases the width of the browser, the edit and delete icons wouldn't be hidden instead it would hide the row as seen in the image below.
[image]
[image]

I made it here https://codesandbox.io/s/learn-mui-data-grid-hover-row-367vh?file=/demo.js but I found **some drawbacks** below:

#### 1. The `Popper` component is rendered on top of the `DataGrid` component

When our mouse cursor hovered the row that was not fully shown, the `Popper` component was shown like these images below.

[image]
[image]

I've tried to add the `disablePortal={true}` prop to the Popper component but it would make the `Popper` component rendered outside the row like this image below.
[image]

I also have tried to change the `zIndex` prop for the column header (became 1000), the row (became 10), and the pagination container (became 1000) of the `DataGrid` component also changed the `zIndex` prop of the `Popper` component (became 100) but still the `Popper` component was rendered on top of the `DataGrid` component like this image below.
[image]

**Question 1: What should I do to make the `Popper` component rendered on the top of the row but still inside the `DataGrid` component like this image below?**
[image]

#### 2. The `Popper` component was not sticking to the `DataGrid` component

If I add a few new columns, the `Popper` component was sticking on the end of the row like this image below. This was the condition I want.

[image]

If we scroll our mouse to the start of the row, the `Popper` component was not sticking to the end of the row like this image below. This was not the condition I want.
[image]

**Question 2: What should I do to make the Popper component stick to the end of the row regardless of scrolling horizontally our mouse like this image below?**
[image]

Here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/learn-mui-data-grid-hover-row-367vh?file=/Demo2.jsx

Or is there any better way to achieve this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Finally, I could make it after learning about these features:

1. column pinning feature https://mui.com/components/data-grid/columns/#column-pinning to create the edit and delete icons container
2. `componentsProps` https://mui.com/components/data-grid/components/#row to control which row is hovered

Here are the steps:

1. use `componentsProps` to control which row is hovered

```js
componentsProps={{
  row: {
    onMouseEnter: onMouseEnterRow,
    onMouseLeave: onMouseLeaveRow
  }
}}
```

2. add `actions` column and only show the edit and delete icons when the row is hovered

```js
{
  field: "actions",
  headerName: "",
  width: 120,
  sortable: false,
  disableColumnMenu: true,
  renderCell: (params) => {
    if (hoveredRow === params.id) {
      return (
        <Box
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: "whitesmoke",
            width: "100%",
            height: "100%",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center"
          }}
        >
          <IconButton onClick={() => console.log(params.id)}>
            <EditIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton onClick={() => console.log(params.id)}>
            <DeleteIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Box>
      );
    } else return null;
  }
}
```

3. pin the `actions` column and change the `DataGrid` styles

```js
<DataGridPro
  // some code here ...
  initialState={{ pinnedColumns: { right: ["actions"] } }}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiDataGrid-iconSeparator": {
      display: "none"
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-pinnedColumnHeaders": {
      boxShadow: "none",
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-pinnedColumns": {
      boxShadow: "none",
      backgroundColor: "transparent",
      "& .MuiDataGrid-cell": {
        padding: 0
      }
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-row": {
      cursor: "pointer",
      "&:hover": {
        backgroundColor: "whitesmoke"
      },
      "&:first-child": {
        borderTop: "1px solid rgba(224, 224, 224, 1)"
      }
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus": {
      outline: "none"
    },
    "& .MuiDataGrid-cell:focus-within": {
      outline: "none"
    }
  }}
/>
```

Here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/learn-mui-data-grid-column-pinning-gzgn0?file=/demo.js

[image]